# If I disable object mesh renderer will it affect anything wrong?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a Sphere that is a child. The problem is that in the game I see it in front of the camera and I don't want to see it but still want to use.

If I uncheck and disable the Mesh Renderer component it might make the Sphere not working as what it needed for ?

[image: Mesh Renderer]

Comment: depends what you mean by using it and wrong

Comment: @BugFinder For example using it as ObjectPickupLocation but if I turn off the mes renderer will I be able yet to use it for Object Pickup Location ? Like a marker to show the Object Pickup Location. In my game I have objects I can pick up so this sphere should mark or get the ObjectPickupLocation the question is if it will work if the mesh renderer is off ?

Comment: Well the mesh renderer is just that, the colliders et al will still be there, so it depends whats needed to make the pickuplocation work..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. The mesh renderer only draws the object in the scene, if it's disabled it will stop drawing it. Everything else will still work: if it has a collider it can collide or be clicked on, if it has a rigid body it will have certain physical properties, it will be found if you call `Object.FindObjectOfType()`, and so on.

Now it's a different story if you disable its game object.